# protogen: create cs file

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protogen

I am trying to use Protogen to create the C# classes this is my syntax

```
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="..\..\ProtoFiles" Command="$(3rdParty)\protobuf\protobuf-net\protogen.exe  --proto_path:ClientsList.proto --csharp_out:ClientsList.cs" />
```

**but there is no C# classes created**

When I used the same proto to create the C++ classes everything worked perfectly (I needed to add syntax="proto2"; I don't know if this may affect the C# part)

if I run it Manually: `C:\3rdParty\protobuf\protobuf-net>protogen.exe  --proto_path:ClientsList.proto --csharp_out:ClientsList.cs`

Usage: protogen [OPTION] PROTO_FILES
Parse PROTO_FILES and generate output based on the options given:

-IPATH, --proto_path=PATH   Specify the directory in which to search for
imports.  May be specified multiple times;
directories will be searched in order.  If not
given, the current working directory is used.

--version                   Show version info and exit.

......

Note that PROTO_FILES can be *.proto or **/*.proto (recursive) when a single
import location is used, to process all schema files found. In recursive mode,
imports from the current directory can also be specified by name-only.

Comment: Does the command work when you run it manually?

Comment: No not even I edit my message to add the Manual, there is no error message nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csharp_out parameter is a folder, not a file, and that isn't how you use proto_path (again, a folder); and it is `=`, not `:` - in your case you probably want:

```
protogen --csharp_out=. ClientsList.proto
```

Note the syntax is intentionally a mirror of the `protoc` command-line syntax.

However! There is also MSBuild package that might make it easier to work with instead of your own custom task, and I'm working on a "generators" implementation - which means zero setup: just add the .proto and run.

Comment: can you please give more information about the generators ? thank you

Comment: @melom "generators" is a brand new feature in the compiler - only available for a few weeks now; I will be making use of it under protobuf-net.BuildTools (only released yesterday - it provides "analyzers" to spot problems in your usage as you type the code, in the IDE or at the command-line). However, the "generators" part is not yet complete.

Comment: @melom here's a now-working example: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.ToolsDemo - you're looking for `UsageDemo/Generators/ShowUsage.cs` and `UsageDemo/Generators/model.proto`